# Initialize function is not invoked during deployment of upgradeable contract

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-deployment, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

This is `initialize` function of my upgradeable contract

```
contract MyContract is
     Initializable,
     ERC20PresetMinterPauserUpgradeable,
     OwnableUpgradeable
{
    function initialize(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
        public
        override
        initializer
    {
        emit ContractInitStarted(_name, _symbol, msg.sender, block.timestamp);
        __ERC20PresetMinterPauser_init(_name, _symbol);
        __Ownable_init_unchained();
        _mint(msg.sender, 500000000 ether);
        emit ContractInitEnded(_name, _symbol, msg.sender, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

This is `2_deploy_contracts.js`

```
const MyContract  = artifacts.require("./MyContract .sol");

const { deployProxy } = require("@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades");

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  await deployProxy(MyContract , ["MyContract  1.0", "TenX"], { deployer, initializer: "initialize" });
};
```

```
npx truffle deploy --network rinkeby
```

Initialize function is never invoked.
Events not triggered
symbol, name, and totalSupply are empty

Perhaps, I must look into `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy`
But not sure

Those are contracts in etherscan:

My address:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x860fa46f170a87df44d7bb867aa4a5d2813127c1

Last 4 transactions for contracts:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6f8dc56c88112cdaedee8610bdb5caf601c145de

AdminUpgradeabilityProxy:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe97ef53dd413729425317a768a0ba425831c5107

ProxyAdmin:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x857411020c5e2b540fdd6c5ed0a4faeb678ef280

Implementation:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x2e4cd3fd7ed77a278d118b95e4bef5b7079367da

Token:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xe97ef53dd413729425317a768a0ba425831c5107

Answer (score 1):

Seems, this is the solution - verification

https://medium.com/etherscan-blog/and-finally-proxy-contract-support-on-etherscan-693e3da0714b